# Recommended TFS 2010 team project setup

Tags: tfs

What is the recommended organizational structure of team projects in TFS 2010? Let's say we have 4 big departments within our enterprise. Is the recommended approach to create a team project for each department or logical representation of one's organization and have different folders for VS projects within those TFS team projects? Or should each reasonable big project have their own team project?

I am asking more from a perspective of code storage and TFS artifacts. If we are to store both code and user stories, tasks, etc. in one big team project, does that hinder the agile development process? We can still setup separate queries and a separate dashboard for each "project" within the big team project. However, the builds would be in this giant list of builds.

If we had many smaller team projects, it would be more difficult for QA to span their work across multiple team projects. They'd need to know where to enter bugs - knowledge that we don't necessarily want to rely on.

So what is the best practice?

Comment: You want everything in a big project just because your QA-guys don't know how to switch connections? Your kidding arent you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing everything in a single project will not hinder "the agile development process".  My recommendation would be to create an area path for each project, and organize your work items under those area paths.  You'll have a product backlog query for each area.  Use the iteration path field to then drive a schedule across all the projects.  That should work fine.  All the reports can then be filtered by area and/or iteration.

For builds, I see many teams prefixing build definitions to provide better organization.  Here's a blog post that describes an extension you can download to help better organize builds.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/04/01/build-folders.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Is this a best practice as outlined by Microsoft, or is this a recommendation based on experience?

Comment: I believe its recommended by MS. We had one of the experts in the local area office going through best practices for TFS and he highly suggested the use of areas over projects. The term project is over used and TFS projects should be renamed to TFS team, group, or department to avoid confusing people. TFS Areas should be setup for any deliverables or shared components.